# Pandas dataframe condition when value in cell is a list

Tags: python, list, pandas, dataframe

How would I find the value of a cell in column `x` on the condition that the value of column `B` in the same row is the list `[0,1]`?

Each cell in columns `A` and `B` are **lists** of integers.

```
               x      y       A       B 
0           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
1           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 1] 
2           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
3           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0]  
4           ding   dong    [0, 1]  [0, 1] 
5           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0] 
6           ding   ding    [0, 1]  [0, 0]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can create `Series` with same index as `DataFrame` and compare it with column `B`:

```
s = pd.Series([[0, 1]], index = df.index)
print s
0    [0, 1]
1    [0, 1]
2    [0, 1]
3    [0, 1]
4    [0, 1]
5    [0, 1]
6    [0, 1]
dtype: object

print df['B'] == s
0    False
1     True
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool

print df[df['B'] == s]
      x     y       A       B
1  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]
4  ding  dong  [0, 1]  [0, 1]

print df.x[df['B'] == s]
1    ding
4    ding
Name: x, dtype: object
```